# how to create overlays for each divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, overlay

I am trying to create overlays for each row in a rails iteration.

```
<% @inquiries.each do |inquiry| %>            
  <div class= "col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">
  </div>
<% end %>
```

For each inquiry, I want to have a button which when clicked, shows an overlay with details of comments on that inquiry.

Each Inquiry has many comments.

A simple overlay can be made by:

```
<div id="overlay">
  <div id="text">Overlay Text</div>
    <button onclick="off()">Turn off overlay</button>
   </div>     

   <div style="padding:20px">
     <h2>Overlay with Text</h2>
      <button onclick="on()">Turn on overlay effect</button>
  </div>  

<script>
function on() {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}

function off() {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
}
</script>

#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#text{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: white;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

But this uses ids for identifying corresponding overlapys. If I use classes, there can't be any identifications and overlays will interfere.

My question is how can I have separate overlays with different contents for each inquiry That means each inquiry has a button which opens an overlay with different items(the inquiry comments) in it.

Answer (score 1):

pass "this" as a parameter in your click function, this will give you access to the current element that was clicked. Then traverse the parameter in your function to access its parent element. Example:

```
<button onclick="on(this)">Turn on overlay effect</button>

function on(clickedElement) {

    clickedElement.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = "block";
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @grey.dim I got the direction. Solved it by using:

```
<div class = "overlayparent">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div id="text">Overlay Text</div>
     <button onclick="off(this)" type="button" class = "btn btn-danger">Turn off overlay</button>
    </div>     

  <div>                        
    <button onclick="on(this)" type="button" class = "btn btn-danger">View/Add Comments</button>
   </div>                       
</div>
```

For javascript I used:

```
<script>
  function on(clickedElement) {
    clickedElement.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("overlay")[0].style.display = "block";        
}

  function off(clickedElement) {
    clickedElement.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("overlay")[0].style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```